# How to get the property wrapper value with $

Tags: swift

Complier emits error when I use $ to visit property wrapper struct.

I am using Xcode 11 beta 5. And I test some code about property wrapper.

```
    class Resolver {
        static var root = Resolver()
        func resolve<Service>(_ serviceType: Service.Type, name: String?) -> Service? {
            return true as? Service
        }
    }

    @propertyWrapper
    struct Injected<Service> {
        private var service: Service?
        public var container: Resolver?
        public var name: String?
        public var wrappedValue: Service {
            mutating get {
                if service == nil {
                    service = (container ?? Resolver.root).resolve(
                        Service.self,
                        name: name
                    )
                }
                return service!
            }
            mutating set {
                service = newValue
            }
        }
    }

    struct AAA {
        @Injected var flag: Bool

        init() {
            print(flag)
            $flag.name = 123
        }
    }

    AAA()
```

I expect the code could be compiled, but there is error when in "$flag.name = 123"

P.S. The same code can be complied with Xcode beta 2

Answer (score 0):

This has changed from $ to _

`_flag.name = 123` should work